# Will tools like shred, wipe or dd (or hard drives in general) check that a write was successful?

Tags: hard-drive, dd, hard-drive-failure, file-shredding, shred

I usually use shred to delete complete hard drives.

But I was wondering if and how tools like shred, wipe or dd verify that the expected bits end up on the hard drive.

Does a hard drive always check after a write?
Or is there some magic in how the magnetic storage thing works that always detects unwritable sectors or incorrect results on writing?

I also use `badblocks -w` to wipe disks. Sure, it takes really long but what happens is quite transparent and I tend to trust it more.

Comment: each of those tools will handle operations differently, but DD will generally break on a bad block unless you are using conv=noerror. keeping in mind that an unwritable sector will remain unwritable, what did you want to have happen in those cases? Personally I use DBAN for wiping disks. follow up with a sledge hammer, and you have a pretty strong solution, suitable for most adversaries.

Comment: *"Does a hard drive always check after a write?"* -- In almost all cases, no, the drive will not perform a *verify* after a write operation.  A sector is typically only deemed "unwritable" if its ID record is corrupted, or  previous reads were uncorrectable.  When a LBA is remapped is up to the drive's controller.

Comment: What does "make a read uncorrectable" mean in simple words? Is that done with some sector-based CRC?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1554322/why-there-is-no-ecc-ram-type-device-invented-to-bypass-bad-sectors-in-hdd