What is the difference between ECC and DDR5's "Built-in Data Checking"?
I just learned that, as part of the standard, DDR5 memory has error correction built-in. However, according to this flyer from Intel, this is not the same as ECC memory:

Is DDR5 memory with built-in data checking the same as traditional ECC memory?
No. Built-in data checking is simply that – a feature that is only capable of checking and correcting a single bit of memory errors, so it doesn't provide data integrity. ECC memory finds these errors and fixes them, providing the robust protection needed for critical data.

I was under the impression that ECC memory was SECDED, meaning it too can only correct one bit.  So my questions are:

What is the difference between DDR5 memory marketed as ECC, and non-ECC DDR5 memory?
What the hell was Intel talking about?


Your "impression" (and the premise of your questions) "that ECC memory ... can only correct one bit" is incorrect.   The wikipedia article on ECC memory does not make that assumption/restriction. There is a footnote that "Most ECC memory uses a SECDED code".  Also see https://superuser.com/questions/1554322/why-there-is-no-ecc-ram-type-device-invented-to-bypass-bad-sectors-in-hdd
